# Transactional data Firebase React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to increment "likes" by 1 after user click on the icon. 
I use Firebase as backend. 
There is a transactional Data function to complete that, but I can"t make it work.

Error is : can't find variable Firebase.

Here is the function onPressIcon

```
onPressIcon(){
var ref = new Firebase('https://streetfrench-a84df.firebaseio.com');
var likes_words = ref.child("items").child("likes");

likes_words.transaction(function(currentLike) {
   return currentLike + 1;
});
}
```

I am very new at this, someone knows how to explain this in details ?

Comment: Please edit with the complete file

Comment: @hellogoodnight, I got this almost working finally. 
My json file:
items{
    word 1{
         def:{}
         likes:{0}
   }
   word 2...

var likes_words = ref.child("items").child("likes"); is creating a new "items". How can I make a relative path to items/.../likes ?
var likes_words = ref.child("items").child(?????).child("likes");

Comment: It looks like you're using a very old version of Firebase. I recommend updating according [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web), or looking at the [current documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) which includes a [section on transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

Comment: Alright, I will have a look at that! their documentation is still referencing the "old" one though! In the meantime, do you know how to make a ref to a relative path  inside a json file ?